# Erasing Value in Array for Minimum Sum Java

Tags: java, arrays, sum, minimum

I am attempting to built a Java program that finds the minimum value of an array by taking out one element that may be repeating. The following is my code.

```
// Don't place your source in a package
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

// Please name your class Main
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = in.nextInt();
        int[] elements = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            elements[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int counter = 1001;
        for (int c = 0; c < elements.length; c++){
            if (sum(elements, c) <= counter){
                counter = sum(elements, c);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(counter);

    }
    public static int sum (int[] e, int n){
        for (int j = 0; j<e.length; j++){
            if (e[j] == n){
                e[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x: e){
            sum+=x;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

I feel like I am making a simple mistake, but I've spent hours looking over the code. Thanks

Comment: Why the value 1001? ..wait! Why this logic and to do what?

Comment: *"finds the minimum value of an array by taking out one element that may be repeating"* : it doesn't make sense to me.What is the link with the minimum value of an array ?

Comment: the title of ur problem and the details are completely different.. u want to erase a min value or find a min value?

Comment: Do want a sum of 2 lowest non-repeating integers in the array? The likelihood of answer depends on how precise is your question.

Comment: Are you trying to take out one repeating element or more than one repeating element? If it's only one then it won't work because you are potentially calling sum twice for each repeating element.

Comment: You Could sort your array using arrays.sort(your array) , or put your array on a treeset, thé treeset is sorted and have only unique éléments.then you get thé elements 0 and 1

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- I would say the key part in this case is "Finally, if your program still has a bug, write down on a piece of paper the exact action you expect the program to take on every line of the program for the broken case. Your program is only twenty lines long. You should be able to write down everything that it does."

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to remove a single element and you could potentially have an element repeating more than once, then you need to change your main loop to:

```
int counter = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for (int c = 0; c < elements.length; c++) {
    counter = Math.min(counter, sum(elements, c));
}
```

This only calls sum once for each element.